# Mongoose Find all Documents by subdocument and filter out subdocs that dont match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I am trying to query all documents in a collection that contain specific user data WITHOUT returning all subdocuments (there are a ton of subdocuments)

**Example Documents**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Document 1",
        "users": [
            { "id": "a", "name": "User 1" },
            { "id": "b", "name": "User 1" },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Document 2",
        "users": [
            { "id": "b", "name": "User 1" },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Document 3",
        "users": [
            { "id": "a", "name": "User 1" },
            { "id": "b", "name": "User 1" },
            { "id": "c", "name": "User 1" },
        ]
    }
]
```

Here we have 3 documents in which use with id A is in 2 of them, to Query all documents where user A exists I am doing:

```
collection.findManyByQuery({
    users: {
        $elemMatch: {
            id: 'a'
        }
    }
})
```

This returns me documents with id 1 and 3 which is correct. HOWEVER I am trying to return the documents with ONLY user A object inside the users array so my result would look like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Document 1",
        "users": [
            { "id": "a", "name": "User 1" },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Document 3",
        "users": [
            { "id": "a", "name": "User 1" },
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried `$unwind: 'users'` and a couple of filters but have not got the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) stage.

According to docs:

> The projection parameter determines which fields are returned in the matching documents

So using `users.$: 1` you are telling mongo: "Return the value from users that matches the criteria". In this case the criteria is `id: "a"`.

```
db.collection.find({
  users: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: "a"
    }
  }
},
{
  "users.$": 1
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eXOsM8zU2Ll)

Also you can use `users.id` into find query like in [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_ScUUlIV2sD)

Maybe is a query more clean, only two lines:

```
db.collection.find({
  "users.id": "a"
},
{
  "users.$": 1
})
```

Edit:

To add more values to output (like `title` or `id`) you have to add to projection stage. By default projection only return the `_id` and the values with `1` or `true`.

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QFcZ8aSE5Aq)

Comment: Great this helps alot! However now it returns only the subdocuments that match and not the rest of the information in the parent document. Is there a way to return the document + the subdocuments like in your solution?

Comment: Yes, add the fields you want to return in the projection. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/)